# Google Spreadsheets Query > Data from 2 Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Hello,

I need help customizing a query formula:

```
=query({B3:D6;E3:G6;H3:J6};"select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1 asc")
```

I would like to integrate this data from “Sheet 1” and “Sheet 2” into the query (see picture):

- Sheet 1 > DATE (criterion> DATE)
- Sheet 2 > LOCATION (criterion> DATE)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YAu05Hidl_eU1JMmzS8TWXEQPbUIC6Gm-ZSQJP1Ha6k/edit?usp=sharing

How do I do that?

Many thanks for the help

Comment: It is not clear what your exact problem is. What is the `criterion` you mention? You already seem to get a result that "integrates" the two "Sheets". What exactly is missing and what did you try to resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the meaning of the red curly brackets? Is there any significance to the dates being the sames in both sheets?

Comment: Where do types D+T come from?

Answer (score 0):

*Slightly modifying your current formula to accommodate the dates and location `lookup`:*

```js
=query(let(Σ;{A3:A6\B3:D6;A3:A6\E3:G6;A3:A6\H3:J6};{Σ\index(xlookup(index(Σ;;1);N:N;M:M;))});"select * where Col2<>'' order by Col2")
```

[image]

***Updated formula to include column_L***:

```js
=query(let(Σ;{A3:A6\B3:D6;A3:A6\E3:G6;A3:A6\H3:J6};{Σ\index(vLOOKUP(index(Σ;;1);choosecols(L:N;3;2;1);{2\3};))});"select * where Col2<>'' order by Col2")
```

Comment: cant get a clear picture of what your are referring to! showcase your expected output **manually** so that it'll be clear on what is expected of...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS7IO.jpg

@rockinfreakshow

I would like to add an additional column L to the query after column G. To do this I tried the following:

=query(let(Σ;{A3:A6\B3:D6;A3:A6\E3:G6;A3:A6\H3:J6};{Σ\index(XLOOKUP(index(Σ;;1);N:N;M:M;L:L;))});"select * where Col2<>'' order by Col2")

L:L; = Error

Thanks for your help Martin

Comment: try the updated formula added to the answer section